# Storyboard Partial Cut remove

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, ios5, xcode4.2

With the new xCode Storyboard function it is posible to switch the view with some prepared switch-modes like:

Style: "Model" 
Transition: "Partial Cut"

So I have tried to use the "Partial Cut", but I don't know how to remove it after put it on the view stack. Is it posible to remove it with some Storyboard functions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to subclass the view controller and put code in for releasing the modal (not model) view controller with dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: — can't do it with just the storyboard, so far as I can tell. Annoying (same situation with popping controllers out of a navigation controller).